# MySQL is 2 hours behind system time

Tags: mysql, freebsd, timezone

Have a FreeBSD box with MySQL server on it.

The system time is correct - For Denmark (Europe/Copenhagen) currently summertime.

```
# date
Fri Jun 17 12:09:56 CEST 2011
```

The MySQL server has timezone set to SYSTEM

```
mysql> show variables like 'time_zone';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| time_zone     | SYSTEM |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the time is 2 hours behind

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-06-17 10:12:24 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I get this into sync?

**Update**

The box also uses NTP syncronization.

*/etc/rc.conf*

```
ntpd_enable="YES"
ntpd_sync_on_start="YES"
```

Comment: is this a virtual instance (ec2 or similar?)

Comment: No, it's a dedicated box running FreeBSD 8.2 as only OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be [the correct answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/127973/how-do-i-make-sure-that-both-my-server-and-mysql-have-the-same-timezone/127988#127988).

*Add the following line to `/etc/my.cnf` in the [mysqld] section and restart:*

```
default-time-zone='Europe/Copenhagen'
```

Now the MySQL time shows correct.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-06-21 13:26:40 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like MySQL is reporting UTC, and date is reporting your local time.  Try:

```
date -u
```

Does that match MySQL?

Comment: Yes it matches.

Answer (score 0):

(Re-) configure your TZ with

```
tzsetup
```

Comment: Is this just to set the timezone on the system? Because then it's the same as copying timezone files to /etc/localtime `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Copenhagen /etc/localtime`

Comment: True, but from the man-page: "the tzsetup utility also determines whether any adjustment is necessary for systems where the hardware clock does not keep UTC": http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tzsetup&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html

Comment: Has this anything to do with the difference in MySQL?

Comment: Well... "date -u" matches time in MySQL, so I think your CMOS clock is set to UTC. You might check the BIOS as well.